# how come ANT javac command adds extra directories?

Tags: ant, javac

I start studying ANT today in order to make Java compiling easier.
I wrote simple ANT script which only use `javac` command.

What I am trying is compile from **.....\head_first\src\com\masatosan\constant.java** (source)

to the destination directory:

**.....\head_first\WEB-INF\classes\com\masatosan\conf**

So the result would look like:

**.....\head_first\WEB-INF\classes\com\masatosan\conf\constant.class**

But I can't figure out why *the actual result adds "/com/masatosan/conf" directories to the destination folder*, so it looks like:

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\WEB-INF\classes\com\masatosan\conf\com\masatosan\constant.class

Could anyone tell me how can I fix this?

ANT

```
<project name="CompileMasatosan" 
    basedir="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\src\com\masatosan">
    <description>
        masatosan compiler
    </description>
    <property name="confSrc" 
        location="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\src\com\masatosan\conf" />
    <property name="confDest"
        location="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\WEB-INF\classes\com\masatosan\conf" />

    <target name="compileConfSrc">
        <javac srcdir="${confSrc}" destdir="${confDest}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

**UPDATE**

I didn't know complier creates directories based on the package name.

The package name of constant.java was com.masatosan.conf so that complier creates "/com/masatosan/conf/"

Comment: com\masatosan\conf is most likely the package you've given in the constant java file

Comment: it looks like the package of constants.class is com.masatosan, and he wants it to be com.masatosan.conf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to tell ANT to change the package because you want Constant.class to be under the com.masatosan.conf package rather than the com.masatosan package.  The Ant compilation process will create the appropriate package subdirectories, which is why you see com\masatosan created under the dest.

I don't think you can tell ANT to change the package of a source file, which is what you're trying to do by injecting an extra conf dir.  You can either create a conf dir and have a `conf\com\masatosan\constants.class` or put it under `classes\com\masatosan\constants.class`, but you can't do `com\masatosan\conf\constants.class` since that changes the package of constants.class to `com.masatosan.conf`

Or simply change the package of constants.class to com\masatosan\conf and change your ant file to to:

`<property name="confDest"
        location="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\WEB-INF\classes" />`

Comment: Thank you for the tip guys! But how does complier know that it should create exactly "/com/masatosan/conf" for me instead of, say, "head_first/com/masatosan/conf"? Oh... is it because package name of constant.java is "com.masatosan.conf" ?

Comment: I got this answer :) http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

Answer (score 3):

Its because of the package name. You have a Java file in package com.masatosan. You can fix this two way either move class to default package or set ${confDest} value to \head_first\WEB-INF\classes\ only.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the compiler is creating the package directory stucture under the destination directory you specify. The `constant` class is in the `com.masatosan` package, so under `classes\com\masatosan\conf`, the compiler creates a further two directories for the package, `com\masatosan`, and places the compiled class (`constant.class`) in there.

Your destination directory should simply be `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\WEB-INF\classes`. The `com` and `masatosan` directories will be created for you.